# Adding custom button on shopify's checkout page

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am working on an app that requires customization on the checkout page. From my research I found that checkout page customization can be done for shopify plus accounts.
Adding a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.

Note: I want to customize checkout page for all the accounts (basic/plus).[image]

Comment: No APP is able to edit the checkout page for basic and advanced Shopify accounts holders. It's an exclusive feature for Plus members only.

Comment: @Onkar so checkout page doesn't allow any customization? I tried to add script, it is working everywhere but the checkout page.

Comment: They can't even allow script over checkout process pages into basic and advanced plans.

Comment: @Onkar so no customization apart from basic color/images customization that we get on dashboard?

Comment: You got it. No customization of checkout for any plan less than Plus. End of story. Deal with it.